# Access to info in DOM Created from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Ok i have an ajax call that i have working perfectly and populating a Div on my page. The problem is that the data that i have on the page is not accessible to my Scripting so i can not modify it.

I can see everything in Firebug but can not see it in the source. So scripting will not work on it for css and jquery

I am using Rails 3

**What i need is to be able to access the TABLE id results so that my datatable CSS and Jquery will style it**

HTML ->

```
<div id="hotload"></div>
```

jQuery to populate with AJAX ->

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var id = $('#id').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/searches/hotload_results/"+ id,
      type: "GET",
      success: function (data) {
        $("#hotload").append(data);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Controller for this Action ->

```
  def hotload_results
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @resultss = @search.searches(params[:hotloads_page])
    @search.update_attributes(:resultss => @resultss.count)
    render :partial => "hotload_results".html_safe, :layout => false
  end
```

Source code -> (only the body)

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="hotload"></div>
```

Firebug ->

```
<div id="hotload"><div id="load_results_table" class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <h1 class="page-header">Search Results</h1>
        <h3 class="page-subheader">&#8203;&#8203;2 Premium Loads</h3>
        <div align="center">
          <b>These are our Premium loads that we are offering. We guarentee 100% payment on these loads</b>
        </div>
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="redmond stripe" id="results">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Updated At</th>
            <th>Hotload</th>
            <th>Updated</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Dest</th>
            <th>Pickup</th>
            <th>Delivery</th>
            <th>ltl</th>
            <th>Equipment</th>
            <th>Length</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>

          <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Updated At</th>
            <th>Hotload</th>
            <th>Updated</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Dest</th>
            <th>Pickup</th>
            <th>Delivery</th>
            <th>ltl</th>
            <th>Equipment</th>
            <th>Length</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
          </tfoot>

          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>2014-10-20 18:05:41 UTC</th>
                <td>
                  <div align="center">
                        <img src="/assets/stopwatch.fw.png">
                  </div></td>
              <td><div align="center">29 days</div></td>
              <td><div align="center">St Louis Area, MO</div></td>
              <td><div align="center">Pine Bluff, AR</div></td>
                  <td>
                    <div align="center">2014-10-26
                    </div></td>
                  <td>
                    <div align="center">2014-10-27
                    </div></td>
              <td><div align="center">Full</div></td>
              <td>
                <div align="center">Reefer
                </div></td>
              <td><div align="center">53</div></td>
              <td>
                <div align="center" class="btn-group">
                  <a href="/hotloads/93260" class="btn btn-info">Show</a>
                  <a user_id="11940" id="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="hot_save btn">Save</a>
                  <a user_id="11940" href="javascript:void(0)" class="cover_link btn btn-primary">Cover</a>
                </div>
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>2014-10-14 14:47:43 UTC</th>
                <td>
                  <div align="center">
                        <img src="/assets/stopwatch.fw.png">
                  </div></td>
              <td><div align="center">about 1 month</div></td>
              <td><div align="center">Springfield, MO</div></td>
              <td><div align="center">Gerald, MO</div></td>
                  <td><div align="center">TBD</div></td>
                  <td><div align="center">TBD</div></td>
              <td><div align="center">Full</div></td>
              <td>
                <div align="center">Reefer
                </div></td>
              <td><div align="center">48</div></td>
              <td>
                <div align="center" class="btn-group">
                  <a href="/hotloads/93259" class="btn btn-info">Show</a>
                  <a user_id="11940" id="" href="javascript:void(0)" class="hot_save btn">Save</a>
                  <a user_id="11940" href="javascript:void(0)" class="cover_link btn btn-primary">Cover</a>
                </div>
              </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

UPDATE:

this is what i have:

[image]

This is what it should look like:

[image]

My jQuery code does not have access to these ELEMENTS

```
jQuery ->
  $('#results').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bJQueryUI: true
    lengthMenu: [[5, 10], [5, 10]]
    dom: '<"toolbar1">frtip'
    aaSorting: [[0, "desc"]]
    bSort: true
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: [ 0 ]
        visible: false
        searchable: false
      }
    ]
  $('#results1').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bJQueryUI: true
    order: [[0, "desc"]]
    dom: '<"toolbar2">frtip'
    aaSorting: [[0, "desc"]]
    bSort: true
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: [ 0 ]
        visible: false
        searchable: false
      }
    ]
  $('#results_length').css("display", "none");
  $('#results1_length').css("display", "none");
  $("div.toolbar1").html('<img src="/assets/flame.fw.png" /> = Hotload <img src="/assets/stopwatch.fw.png" /> = Timed Load (timed Loads are good for 2 hrs)');
  $("div.toolbar2").html('<b>Theses are loads offered by other Shippers</b>');
```

***UPDATE to THIS:***

Barry T. Smith was right with the callback... 
   I needed to rebuild the datatables after the Success of the AJAX Call.

can do this a couple of ways:

[fnDrawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback)

or by the way i did mine:

```
var id = $('#id').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/searches/hotload_results/"+ id,
      type: "GET",
      success: function (data) {
        $("#hotload").append(data);
        $('#results').dataTable( {
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
          "bJQueryUI": true, 
          "lengthMenu": [[5,10],[5,10]],
          "dom":'<"toolbar1">frtip',
          "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
          "bSort": true,
          "columnDefs": [ {
             "targets": [ 0],
             "visible": false,
             "searchable": false
          } ]
        })
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
      }
    });
```

Comment: FYI, `$("#hotload").ready(...);` is just incorrect syntax for `$(document).ready(...);`

Comment: will fix that thanks but still need to figure out how to be able to access the table in the DOM

Comment: What is the javascript that isn't working for you?

Comment: Regarding your issue, what's wrong with targeting element once it is added to the DOM? Is it dynamic ID or what? I'm really not sure to understand your issue

Comment: The Target i need is not in the SOURCE... I need to access The Table

Comment: CSS should work just fine for dynamically-added elements.

Comment: DOM functions work with the updated DOM, the source is irrelevant.

Comment: `I need to access The Table` So what's wrong with: `$("#hotload").append(data).find('table')...;` ? In fact, what is your issue? Some plugins, some events, or what? And CSS as no issue with any dynamic element

Comment: Added new information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access anything added via AJAX as long as your code is attempting to execute *after* the AJAX has successfully called.

This could be as simple as putting the AJAX call in front of your other scripts that are binding events, etc. If you're getting the AJAX at `$(document).ready()`, you could also move your set of functions to something like `$(window).load()` instead to make sure it happens after the AJAX. Probably the best way would be to call a callback function on the .success of the AJAX method.

For events like click, focus, etc, you could use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('body').on('click', '#results', function(){
   // this does something when you click the table with id of results
});
```

Basically, in this scenario, any time you click the body, it's looking to see if what you clicked was the `#results` element, then does something.

But in summary, if jQuery is looking for `$('#results')` before it has been loaded onto the page, it won't find anything. Wait until after the AJAX, and it should work.

Comment: The AJAX call take 10 - 15 seconds to Complete that is why i went to ajax. it was a normal page that took 10 - 15 sec to load

Comment: Then this is probably the right answer, as your code previously relied on those elements existing on initial page load. Just move the parts relevant to the hotload section to a separate function, and call that function after loading the data.

Comment: Yeah, if it takes that long, you'll definitely want to use a callback function in the AJAX.

Comment: I am sorry i am Very new to Jquery/Javascript/Coffeescript and been researching everything but on click event i dont think will work because i want the results to load. on load  but cant find a onload event that would work. so i went with the $(document).ready

Comment: So i need to implement a call back on the ajax to try to reload the $("result").datatable ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but yes, I would do whatever you want to do to that table in the callback function. See the "success" section here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You're appending your result straight to the div, so my guess is the browser renders this as html but jquery sees it as a string, and not the individual elements. If your controller method returns a string, this is probably the case.

Comment: So is there a fix. that can be implemented by this solution?

Comment: Please expand your answer to include some details